# Finding a vector that is in two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

The following question has been posed to me:

You are given two subspaces $U$, $V$, both in $\mathbb{R}^n$, each with a basis of column vectors forming the columns of the respective matrices $U$, $V$. Find a vector $\vec{x}$ in both subspaces $U$, $V$. That is, find a vector $\vec{x}$ that can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors for $U$ and as a linear combination of the basis vectors for $V$. That means $\vec{x} = U\vec{a} = V\vec{b}$ for some coefficient vectors $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$. Do this for the following two examples:

$$U = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-2&1\\-3&2\\-1&2\end{bmatrix}, V = \begin{bmatrix}0&4\\2&-8\\7&-6\\5&-2\end{bmatrix}$$

I have tried setting up a system of equations by distributing out the $a$s from $\vec{a}$, and the $b$s from $\vec{b}$, and ended up with the system that went

$$a_1 = 4b_2$$
$$-2a_1 + x_2 = 2y_1 - 8y_2$$
$$...$$
and so on, but this lead me to a dead end; they seem to me to be inconsistent unless the vector $\vec{x}$ is the zero vector.

The zero vector seems like it technically should work - It's a vector that's by definition in both subspaces and so can be written as a linear combination of those two, but it seems too trivial of an answer. Am I missing something, or is it really that simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $U (-4,4)^T + V (-2,1)^T = 0$.

In particular, $U (-4,4)^T = (-4,12,20,12)^T = V(2,-1)$.

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: Guesswork. I thought it was entirely trivial, discovered it wasn't, but a tweak of my initial guess worked.

Comment: You are looking for a non-trivial element of the kernel of $\begin{bmatrix} U & V \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Ah. Okay, I re-ran the algebra on the system of equations -- I made an arithmetic error -- frustrating. I now get what you do, and also a means of generating more vectors. Thank you!

Comment: Delighted to help.